# Programmable datasource for file download control?

Tags: xpages

I want a file download on my page where I look up the attachemnts to be displayed from another document based on the value of a field.

I tried a couple of things including returning the value obtained from `NotesRichTextItem.GetEmbeddedObject` but everyting I try I get the error `java.util.Vector incompatible with [Lcom.ibm.xsp.model.FileRowData`

What do I need to call to return a proper value to my file download control?

I realize I could proably display the attachment links using a repeat control but was hoping there was an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FileDownload control requires a NotesDocumentDataSource. There's no way around that. So you could add a panel to you page, add a Notes Document DataSource to that panel that computes the UNID of that document, add a file download control bound to that panel and you are good to go. The FileDownload control will show all files in that document.

Keep in mind: an XPage is not bound to a (one) document and can contain as many data sources as needed.

If you want to construct the URLs yourself, check [the cheatsheet](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM)

Comment: Thanks.  I went with using your cheat sheet and using a repeat control.  It seemed more straight forward.

Comment: If all you need are links to the attachments, then a repeat control is probably the lightest solution. One trick: use a @AttachmentNames in a view column and you don't need to open documents in code